# breeze nav properties have "Detached" status if changed between consecutive queries

Tags: breeze

This bug is somewhat difficult to describe but I'll do my best to describe the sequence.

1. Using EntityManager em1, query Entity A and it's nav property (R1) Entity B1.
2. Using EntityManager em2, query A and change it's nav property to B2.  Save the change.
3. Using EntityManager em1, still holding A and B1, query A, including it's expanded nav property R1.
4. In R1.subscribeChanges, the correct new value of B2 will exist as R1's value but it will have a status of "Detached".

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've tried and been **unable** to repro your issue. Per your description:

1. Using EntityManager em1, query Entity A and it's nav property (R1) Entity B1.
2. Using EntityManager em2, query A and change it's nav property to B2. Save the change.
3. Using EntityManager em1, still holding A and B1, query A, including it's expanded nav property R1.
4. In R1.subscribeChanges, the correct new value of B2 will exist as R1's value but it will have a status of "Detached".

My test is shown below ( and passes).

```
test("query nav prop change and expand", function() {
    var em1 = newEm();
    var em2 = newEm();
    var p = Predicate.create("freight", ">", 100).and("customerID", "!=", null);
    var query = new breeze.EntityQuery()
        .from("Orders")
        .where(p)
        .expand("customer")
        .take(1);
    stop();
    var oldCust, newCust1a, newCust1b, order1, order1a, order1b;
    em1.executeQuery(query).then(function(data) {
        order1 = data.results[0];
        oldCust = order1.customer;
        ok(oldCust != null, "oldCust should not be null");
        return em2.executeQuery(EntityQuery.fromEntityKey(order1.entityAspect.getKey()));

    }).then(function(data2) {
        order1a = data2.results[0];
        ok(order1.entityAspect.getKey().equals(order1a.entityAspect.getKey()), "order keys should be the same");

        var customerType = em2.metadataStore.getEntityType("Customer");
        newCust1a = customerType.createEntity();
        newCust1a.setProperty("companyName", "Test_compName");
        order1a.setProperty("customer", newCust1a);
        return em2.saveChanges();
    }).then(function (sr) {
        em1.entityChanged.subscribe(function(args) {
            var entity = args.entity;
            ok(entity != null, "entity should not be null");
            ok(entity.entityAspect.entityState != EntityState.Detached, "entityState should not be detached");
        });
        return em1.executeQuery(query);
    }).then(function(data3) {
        order1b = data3.results[0];
        ok(order1b == order1, "should be the same order");
        newCust1b = order1b.customer;
        ok(newCust1a.entityAspect.getKey().equals(newCust1b.entityAspect.getKey()), "customer keys should be the same");
        ok(newCust1b != null, "newCust1b should not be null");
        ok(newCust1b.entityAspect.entityState.isUnchanged(), "should be unchanged");
    }).fail(testFns.handleFail).fin(start);
});
```

At this point I really need a repro to go any further.  Please use the DocCode sample ( which is a collection of unit tests) in the Breeze zip to create a breaking unit test case and post it here.